# Puppet nested resources create_resources, can't convert string into hash

Tags: puppet

trying to build a DNS with this module: [ref](https://forge.puppet.com/camptocamp/bind). But getting this error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, can't convert String into Hash.
```

I have nested YAML, but not sure if it's correctly formatted or not or problems with something else within my code. 
This is my dns profile dns.pp:

```
class profile::bind {

  validate_hash($conf)
  $conf   = hiera_hash('bind::zone', undef)
  create_resources('profile::bind::make::zone', $conf)

}
```

This is how I define my zone with make_zone.pp:

```
define profile::bind::make::zone (
  $hash_data,
  $zone,
  $ensure,
  $zone_contact,
  $zone_ns,
  $zone_serial,
  $zone_ttl,
  $zone_origin,
) {

  validate_hash($hash_data)

  bind::zone { $zone :
    ensure       => $ensure,
    zone_contact => $zone_contact,
    zone_ns      => [$zone_ns],
    zone_serial  => $zone_serial,
    zone_ttl     => $zone_ttl,
    zone_origin  => $zone_origin,
  }
}
```

This is my host1.yaml data:

```
---
version: 5

bind::zone:
  zone: test.ltd
  ensure: present
  zone_contact: 'contact.test.ltd'
  zone_ns: 
    -'ns0.test.ltd'
    -'ns1.test.ltd'
  zone_serial: '2018010101'
  zone_ttl: '767200'
  zone_origin: 'test.ltd'
  hash_data:
    "newyork":
      owner: "11.22.33.44"
    "tokyo":
      owner: "22.33.44.55"
    "london":
      owner: "33.44.55.66"

bind::cname:
  ensure: present
  record_type: master
```

Comment: It is extremely suspicious that class `profile::bind` calls `validate_hash($conf)` *before* assigning a value to `$conf`.  I cannot imagine any way in which that would produce desirable behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of mistakes and misunderstandings in the code. I fixed them up so that the code at least compiles and ended up with this.

Changes to profile::bind:

```
class profile::bind {
  include bind
  $conf = lookup('bind::zone')
  create_resources(profile::bind::make::zone, $conf)
}
```

Changes to profile::bind::make::zone:

```
define profile::bind::make::zone (
  Enum['present','absent'] $ensure,
  String         $zone_contact,
  Array[String]  $zone_ns, 
  String         $zone_serial,
  String         $zone_ttl,
  String         $zone_origin,
  Hash[String, Hash[String, String]] $hash_data,
) {
  bind::zone { $name:
    ensure       => $ensure,
    zone_contact => $zone_contact,
    zone_ns      => $zone_ns,
    zone_serial  => $zone_serial,
    zone_ttl     => $zone_ttl,
    zone_origin  => $zone_origin,
  }
}
```

Changes to host1.yaml:

```
---
bind::zone:
  'test.ltd':
    ensure: present
    zone_contact: 'contact.test.ltd'
    zone_ns:
      - 'ns0.test.ltd'
      - 'ns1.test.ltd'
    zone_serial: '2018010101'
    zone_ttl: '767200'
    zone_origin: 'test.ltd'
    hash_data:
      "newyork":
        owner: "11.22.33.44"
      "tokyo":
        owner: "22.33.44.55"
      "london":
        owner: "33.44.55.66"
```

Some explanation:

**immediate problem**:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, can't convert String into Hash.
```

This error was caused because your Hiera data was not correctly structured as a `Hash[String, Hash[String, String]]`. Notice in the yaml I have removed your key "zone" and created a nested Hash there.

**must include the bind class**

The camptocamp BIND module requires the bind class to also be declared. See its documentation.

**validate_hash function is legacy and in the wrong place**

As John Bollinger mentioned in the comment, you had the `validate_hash` on the wrong line. I think that was a cut/paste issue, because you would have got a different error message if that was really your code. Anyway, since you're using Puppet 5 (I guess that by the version => 5 in your Hiera), don't use the legacy validate functions ; use Puppet's data type validation. So I just deleted that line.

**use lookup() instead of hiera_hash()**

Again, since you're using Puppet 5, use the `lookup()` function instead of the deprecated `hiera_hash()` function.

**version 5 belongs in hiera.yaml, not host1.yaml**

It won't cause you any problems, but the line `version: 5` won't do anything here, and it belongs in your `hiera.yaml` file. I used a hiera.yaml file as follows for testing:

```
---
version: 5
defaults:
  datadir: data
  data_hash: yaml_data
hierarchy:
  - name: "Host 1"
    paths:
    - host1.yaml
```

**zone_ns type confusion**

You had 2 problems with the `zone_ns` - firstly, a typo in your YAML (no space after the `-`) ; and secondly, you passed in an Array of zone NS's and then tried to coerce the array to an array in your defined type.

**zone parameter should be the name var**

Notice I had to delete the `$zone` parameter in your defined type, and I used the special `$name` variable instead, to get the name from the title.

**refactored to use data type validation**

Notice how I used Puppet's data type validation on your inputs in the defined type, and then I had no further need for the legacy `validate_hash` function and other related validate functions. Read more about that [here](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_data_type.html).

I think that's all. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Much cleaner code with your answer!